# Retrieve data as group in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an MongoDB collection with 100 records, in NodeJs I want retrieve as 10 records with each containing 10 records, how do I do that

Comment: Does order matter or perhaps some kind of way to group them?

Comment: Order doesn’t matter, just retrieve all and group without duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If you want the records to be distinct you can use the Set object to help with that. The function takes a function that gets the key of the item so we know how to differentiate them.

```
function groupByDistinct(records, groupSize, getKey) {
    const set = new Set();
    let result = [], current = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = records.length; i < l; i++) {
        const value = records[i], key = getKey(value);
        if (set.has(key) {
            continue;
        }
        set.add(key);
        current.push(value);
        if (current.length === groupSize) {
            result.push(current);
            current = [];
        }
    }
    if (current.length !== 0) {
        result.push(current);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example Usage

```
groupByDistinct(records, 10, x => x.key);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way it could be done by MongoDB queries

Comment: @veeRN - Well I did assume you already had the data pulled. There must be a way to do it in MongoDB honestly.

Comment: Ok, the data could grow upto 30000 records, I don’t want to go thru 30000 records and group it by 10 or 100 , looking for some ways to have the data retrieved as set of 10’s or 100’s

Comment: @veeRN - 30k is not too bad, 300k might be a problem. You would need some kind of windowing function to do this but I'm not familiar with everything available in MongoDB. We would both have to hit the docs.

Comment: @veeRN - I say give both a shot but who knows you might get a MongoDB pro shortly.